# How to do asymptotic analysis on this weird recurrence?

Tags: algorithm, big-o, asymptotic-complexity, recurrence

I came across this weird recurrence equation:

```
T(n,h) = T(n/2, h1) + T(n/2, h-h1) + nh
```

and:

```
T(1,h) = O(h)
```

I need to find the **asymptotic upper bound**. I have never come across a recurrence relation with two arguments.

After much searching I found this set of [slides](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~eppstein/pubs/Epp-SODA-04-qaba.pdf) which indicates to me that it is related to computational geometry.

It would be nice if someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: What is `h1` here? That recurrence looks like it goes negative pretty quickly.

Comment: I'm not sure. The question doesn't mention anything except for this: that we can assume T(n)=O(1) and n = O(1)

Comment: You can solve such a bi-variate recursive function using generating functions, like [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/697731/how-to-solve-this-recurrence-relation-with-sigma-notation-fn-m-fn-1-m).

Comment: @MohamedEnnahdiElIdrissi is there any place I can read the theory for this?

Comment: [Here](http://www.cs.uccs.edu/~jkalita/algorithms.pdf) and [there](http://www.matematica.net/portal/e-books/Graham%20-%20Knuth%20-%20Patashnik%20-%20%20Concrete%20Mathematics.pdf).

Comment: `h1` is a mere constant, I believe.

Comment: Don't you think the recursive relation should look like this:
`T(n,h) = T(n/2, h) + T(n/2, h-h1) + nh`?
`h` instead of `h1` in the first recursive call, no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that n is a power of 2, 0 <= h1 <= h, T(0, h) = 0, and T(1, h) = h, an upper bound is 2nh by the following inductive proof.

Basis: T(0, h) <= 0 <= 2(0)h, and T(1, h) <= h <= 2(1)h.

Inductive step: T(n, h) = T(n/2, h1) + T(n/2, h - h1) + nh <= 2(n/2)h1 + 2(n/2)(h - h1) + nh <= 2nh, regardless of h1.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the first recursive call includes `h` instead of `h1`, and replacing `h1` by `c` (for the sake of readability), I decided to proceed like the following:

[image]

[image]